# Cookie note returned when using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I have set a couple of cookies for my site, one of which is access_token.  The cookie is set to domain 'localhost' and expires in the future.

You can see from my test route what I run and the result I get (as the comment)

> of course the dd() are run 1 at a time.

```
Route::get('test', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $req) {
    dd($req->cookie('access_token')); //returns null
    dd($_COOKIE['access_token']); //returns my cookie
});
```

When I dump the `$req` object, it shows all the cookie keys, but only the laravel_session cookie is not null.

[image]

UPDATE:

```
dd($request->hasCookie('access_token'));
```

also returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you're using the EncryptCookies middleware, but the cookie isn't encrypted.

Edit your [`app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.0/app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php) and add the cookie names to the $except array to let them pass-through untouched.

Comment: Ahh.. ya, i think this is the issue... but I need to be able to do this via my service provider so users of the package dont have to do it.